# How to format answer in answer package?

Tags: answers

I use `answers` package. In out put of answer, I want to format `1)` or `Answer 1.` instead of `1` as default. How can I do it? My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\begin{ex}
This is a question.
\begin{sol}
This is an answer.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Ansewr}
 \input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you declare

```
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
```

you can use

```
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\emph{Solution #1}}
```

Instead of `\emph{Solution #1}` do whatever formatting you need.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\textbf{Answer #1.}}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\begin{ex}
This is a question.
\begin{sol}
This is an answer.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Answer}
 \input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

[image]