# Inserting R code chunks in Rmarkdown making an error

Tags: pdftex, r, rmarkdown

My little demo code borrows from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231600/) is given as follows (**test.rmd**):

````
---
documentclass: article
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    keep_tex: no
geometry: "left = 2.5cm, right = 2cm, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm"
fontsize: 11pt
header-includes:
- \newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
- \usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers} 
- \Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
- \renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\textbf{Answer.}}
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  error = TRUE,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE
)
```

\section{Problems}

\begin{ex}
First exercise
\begin{sol}
First solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
````

It works well. However, when I inset some R code chunks in it like

````
\begin{ex}
Second exercise
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
```{r}
1+2
```
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
````

it makes an error showing

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

**Weirdly**, we can use the R code chunks outside the environments `\begin{ex}...\end{ex}` and `\begin{sol}...\end{sol}`!

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Please always show the full generated LaTeX code in this case. Not everyone here uses Rmarkdown but many of us can debug LaTeX code and explan what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The output of the sum is `## [1] 3` and including it in a LaTeX environment it passed to the LateX engine as markdown text:

````
```r
1+2
```

```
## [1] 3
```
````

The result is the same fatal error that type  "#" unescaped in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello #  
\end{document}
```

One solution is specify not only what is R code, but also what is LaTeX within the markdown,  but **excluding** the R chunk inside, that is:

````
```{=tex}
\begin{ex}
Second exercise
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
```

```{r}
1+2
```

```{=tex}
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
```
````

Then the R chunk is processed before to pass it to the LaTeX export:

[image: mwe]

Comment: +1 perfect explanation

Comment: It works! Great!  I just wandering  whether we can fix the problem via the setting in preamble or yaml part of the rmd file @Fran As we known, if there are too many code chunks in the file, your solution may be somewhat inconvenient ...

Comment: @JohnStone It's just a matter of being aware of the order in which each language are processed,  to avoid nesting  in the wrong order. You can combine `**foo \emph{bar} baz**` to produce `\textbf{foo \emph{bar} baz}` without mark anything as LaTeX code, but the opposite will not work (i.e., `\textbf{foo *bar* baz}`)  because the algorithm *must* assume that here  "`*bar*`" is LaTeX too, and the same apply with the R chunks, only that with one more layer of possible wrong nesting.